# downloading a file from a web directory

Tags: php, security, http, authentication, .htaccess

i have a form which allows the user to upload some files to a folder.

i've edit the .htaccess file in that directory to protect this folder from allowing the unwanted visitors to download the contents manually by typing the full url
ex:
http://www.bkabkabka.com/a/b/c/document.pdf

and this is the .htaccess data

```
Options All -Indexes
<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|doc|pdf|docx)$">
 Order Allow,Deny
 Deny from all
```

i have another administration page which allows the responsible guy from our side to download the files by filtering them to anything he want and then click on a html link to normally download the files.
ex:

```
id             name          filename
1             aaaaa     -->  filename1   <-- this is href link which contains for example http://www.bkabkabka.com/a/b/c/2.doc
```

the problem is that the htaccess modification is applying globaly and i want to create like a username and password to this folder and then use **PHP** code to connect to this folder and be able to download the files normally.

how can i do that?

thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the easiest way to password protect a directory with apache is htpasswd:

add to your .htaccess in the root dir of the protected directory tree:

```
AuthUserFile /home/user/www/protected/.htpasswd
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Protected"
Require valid-user
```

then run this from the comand line and enter the desired password:

```
htpasswd -c /home/user/www/protected/.htpasswd user
```

you can add another user like so:

```
htpasswd /home/user/www/protected/.htpasswd user2
```

to download files in this protected dir with php, use basic authentication. that is construct a url like so: http://user:password@server/protected/file.txt

re your comment, in cpanel there's a "Password Protect Directories" feature accessible from the main page. Here's some detail on that:

http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/pass_protected_directories.htm

if you're planning to store the uploaded files in your protected directory, you would just want to make sure move_uploaded_file copies the file to the right path, e.g.:

```
move_uploaded_file($tmpPath, "/home/user/www/protected/$name");
```

Comment: currently i'm using cpanel to control the hosting package forour company which we have bought from an ISP. so i don't know if i will beable to run commands from the cpanel.

another thing.. what about the upload part do i have to make some changes to the code.

Comment: $uploaddir = 'uploads'; // Where you want the files to upload to - Important: Make sure this folders permissions is 0777!
$allowed_ext = 'doc,docx,pdf'; // These are the allowed extensions of the files that are uploaded
$max_size = '1000000'; // 50000 is the same as 50kb
$tempFilename=$_FILES['cv-file']['tmp_name'];
$Filename=$_FILES['cv-file']['name'];
$Filesize=$_FILES['cv-file']['size'];
if(is_uploaded_file($tempFilename))
{
if(move_uploaded_file($tempFilename ,$uploaddir.'/'.$newFilename))
{//ok}}

Answer (score 1):

You can actually specify a [username/password combination directly in `.htaccess`](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/3), no PHP code required. This will give you basic HTTP level authentication which might be good enough for you. But beware, it's pretty weak from a security standpoint. But it will keep the lazy  people out.